# LibreOffice core, error when running make

Tags: git, makefile, centos7, libreoffice

git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core

cd ~/core/

./autogen.sh --with-lang=en_US

make

After a few minutes running it shows the following error:

```
cd /home/liandro/core/external/tarballs/tmp && bash -c 'wget --progress=dot:mega -Q 0 -P "." -l 0 -nd -nH -N --no-use-server-timestamps https://dev-www.libreoffice.org/extern/8249374c274932a21846fa7629c2aa9b-officeotron-0.7.4-master.jar 2>&1 | tee -a /home/liandro/core/external/tarballs/fetch.log && [ $PIPESTATUS -eq 0 ]' && SUM=shasum -a 256 8249374c274932a21846fa7629c2aa9b-officeotron-0.7.4-master.jar | sed "s/ .*//" && if test "$SUM" != "f2443f27561af52324eee03a1892d9f569adc8db9e7bca55614898bc2a13a770"; then echo ERROR: expected checksum for 8249374c274932a21846fa7629c2aa9b-officeotron-0.7.4-master.jar is f2443f27561af52324eee03a1892d9f569adc8db9e7bca55614898bc2a13a770 2>&1 | tee -a /home/liandro/core/external/tarballs/fetch.log; false; fi && mv 8249374c274932a21846fa7629c2aa9b-officeotron-0.7.4-master.jar ../
--2022-09-19 15:17:15-- https://dev-www.libreoffice.org/extern/8249374c274932a21846fa7629c2aa9b-officeotron-0.7.4-master.jar
Resolving dev-www.libreoffice.org (dev-www.libreoffice.org)... 89.238.68.201, 2a00:1828:a012:201::1
Connecting to dev-www.libreoffice.org (dev-www.libreoffice.org)|89.238.68.201|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2448421 (2.3M) [application/java-archive]
Saving to: ‘./8249374c274932a21846fa7629c2aa9b-officeotron-0.7.4-master.jar’

 0K ........ ........ ........ ........ .....            100%  620K=3.9s

2022-09-19 15:17:20 (620 KB/s) - ‘./8249374c274932a21846fa7629c2aa9b-officeotron-0.7.4-master.jar’ saved [2448421/2448421]

    cd /home/liandro/core && ./g -f clone
    Submodule 'translations' (git://anongit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/translations) registered for path 'translations'
    usage: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b ] [-f|--force] [--name ] [--reference ] [--] []
    or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [...]
    or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [...]
    or: git submodule [--quiet] deinit [-f|--force] [--] ...
    or: git submodule [--quiet] update [--init] [--remote] [-N|--no-fetch] [-f|--force] [--rebase] [--reference ] [--merge] [--recursive] [--] [...]
    or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--summary-limit ] [commit] [--] [...]
    or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive]
    or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--recursive] [--] [...]
    make: *** [get-submodules] Error 1

[liandro@local core]$ make
cd /home/liandro/core && ./g -f clone
usage: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b ] [-f|--force] [--name ] [--reference ] [--] []
or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [...]
or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [...]
or: git submodule [--quiet] deinit [-f|--force] [--] ...
or: git submodule [--quiet] update [--init] [--remote] [-N|--no-fetch] [-f|--force] [--rebase] [--reference ] [--merge] [--recursive] [--] [...]
or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--summary-limit ] [commit] [--] [...]
or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive]
or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--recursive] [--] [...]
make: *** [get-submodules] Error 1
[liandro@local core]$
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely because you are using an old version of git. Try with a newer version (updated packages? Even building it from sources if necessary) and it should work.

Comment: Thank You, update git https://computingforgeeks.com/install-git-2-on-centos-7/

Comment: Also, `./g` is… what?

Comment: I guess it's one script in the project?